# ASP.Net C# - Catching errors when sending an email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, error-handling, try-catch

So I've got a function to send an email which I run within a button click event after some validation.  However, how do I catch any errors when sending an email?  I'm familiar with the try-catch-finally approach so would the code at the bottom be sufficient?

```
protected void sendEmail(string activationCode, string username, string emailAddress)
{
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("EMAIL");
    mail.To.Add(emailAddress);
    mail.Subject = "Please activate your account.";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    string htmlBody;
    htmlBody = "Dear " + username + "<br /><br />";
    htmlBody += "Thank you for registering an account.  Please activate your account by visiting the URL below:<br /><br />";
    htmlBody += "http://localhost:57167/signin.aspx?activate=" + activationCode + "<br /><br />";
    htmlBody += "Thank you.";
    mail.Body = htmlBody;
    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("EMAIL", "PASSWORD");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
```

Is something like this okay?

```
protected void sendEmail(string activationCode, string username, string emailAddress)
{
    try
    {
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("EMAIL");
    mail.To.Add(emailAddress);
    mail.Subject = "Please activate your account.";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    string htmlBody;
    htmlBody = "Dear " + username + "<br /><br />";
    htmlBody += "Thank you for registering an account.  Please activate your account by visiting the URL below:<br /><br />";
    htmlBody += "http://localhost:57167/signin.aspx?activate=" + activationCode + "<br /><br />";
    htmlBody += "Thank you.";
    mail.Body = htmlBody;
    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("EMAIL", "PASSWORD");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
    catch
    {
        lblError.Text = "error message";
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: You should not `try` that much code, only put the code where exceptions may occur inside the  `try-catch` block.

Comment: I catch SmtpException and Exception - this seems to handle most things that go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change some things. See code below:

```
using(SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com"))
{
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("EMAIL");
    mail.To.Add(emailAddress);
    mail.Subject = "Please activate your account.";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    string htmlBody;
    htmlBody = "Dear " + username + "<br /><br />";
    htmlBody += "Thank you for registering an account.  Please activate your account by visiting the URL below:<br /><br />";
    htmlBody += "http://localhost:57167/signin.aspx?activate=" + activationCode + "<br /><br />";
    htmlBody += "Thank you.";
    mail.Body = htmlBody;
    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("EMAIL", "PASSWORD");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    try
    {
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

1. Using statement to dispose of the SmtpClient correctly, whether it fails or not.
2. Move the assignments outside of the try-catch.
3. Even though I am against catching general exceptions (you should know what kind of exceptions to expect); use `ex.Message` to display relevant exception-information.

Comment: To use "Using" statement. the class should implement IDisposable interface. The SmtpClient class doesn't implement IDisposable interface, so there is no Dispose method available for that.

Answer (score 3):

You should handle the exception using **[SmtpException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpexception(v=vs.110).aspx)** by accessing its **statuscode** property.

Also put your **Try** blocks only where you think exception's may occur.

```
        try
        {
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be more or less sufficient (depending on what you're trying to do).

The best approach would be to leave the current method as is (first listing), then have another one a la:

```
public void dispatchEmail(string activationCode, string username, string emailAddress)
{
  try
  {
      this.sendEmail(activationCode, username, emailAddress);
  }
  catch (Exception e) // Note: This is considered bad practice, might want to check for specific exceptions
  {
   lblError.Text = "error message: " + e.ToString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by zaitsman is what I would do generally. On top of that, if its a requirement for you to make a non- blocking call to send the email (so that rest of the application does not wait for the email to deliver and can carry on with rest of the work) you should use TPL and make a non -blocking call to the email sender. Something like this -

```
 Task emailTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dispatchEmail();
```